# Monitoring Exceptions raised by an executable

Tags: windows, linux, seh, exception

Using tools like strace I can figure out the signals a program receives as it executes, regardless of whether or not signal handlers for those signals have been defined.

[EDIT]
In order to do the same on Windows I'm following what's mentioned [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/dau-blog/how-to-capture-exceptions-in-process-monitor-traces-using-pocdump). I tested it by having a test process sleep at the start for about 20 seconds, then crash by jumping to 0x41414141. As it sleeps I attach procdump.exe to the process and then monitor the exceptions in procmon.exe. Is there a way I can do this without the sleep? I tried running it from OllyDbg and then attaching procdump.exe but the message would say that the process is already being debugged.

Any advice on how I could proceed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use the `-x` command line argument for [ProcDump](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/dd996900.aspx):

> `-x`  Launch the specified image with optional arguments. If it is a Store Application or Package, ProcDump will start on the next
>   activation (only).
>
> ...
>
> Launch a process and then monitor it for exceptions:
>
> `C:\>procdump -e 1 -f "" -x c:\dumps consume.exe`